# C++ Delay For-Loop without pausing Console

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a function that will be done many times over and over but with a pause in between each cycle.

I have tried to use "sleep" but that pauses the console. And I have searched online and only found answers that paused the console during usual.

**Code:**

```
int i;
for(i=0; i<500; i++) {
    std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
}
```

How can I make it print "Hello" 500 times and as well allow the user to use the console while it is doing the said function?

Comment: If you want to allow the user to keep using the console, you will need an additional thread. Even then, the output will mix with the user's inputs. See [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) and [std::async](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux This is just an example. Just allow user input while doing some background task is my goal.

Comment: @JohanDoe The thing is that there's going to be unusual consequences of trying to multithread even basic code like this. It's certainly possible to allow the user to input text in between print statements, using some basic multithreading, but you're going to get interleaved text as a result: `"ThiHello\ns is a user tyHello\nping into the conHello\nsole while statemeHello\nnts are being printed.Hello\n"` (obviously the `\n` codes are meant to be line-breaks)

Comment: Creating an interactive text-based user-interface is a non-trivial task. As such, I'd suggest using a framework such as [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses)

Comment: @JohanDoe Saying "This is just an example" doesn't really help. It's not clear what you really want or whether you're asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should include a detailed, accurate explanation and/or example, so that people can write useful answers without having to infer what you really want. If the background task that you want to run is not 'print text to the console', then don't write an example that prints text to the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As some people commented, you need to create an async task in order to do some work while still handling user input.

The following is a minimal, working example about how to acomplish this task by using a thread. It is based on boost so you'll have to link it using `-lboost_thread lboost_system`:

```
g++ test.cpp -lboost_thread -lboost_system -o test
```

The code has several comments in order to explain what you should do:

```
#include <queue>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

// set by the main thread when the user enters 'quit'
bool stop = false;
boost::mutex stopMutex; // protect the flag!


// the function that runs in a new thread
void thread_function() {
    // the following is based on the snippet you wrote
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<500; i++) {
        // test if I have to stop on each loop
        {
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(stopMutex);
            if (stop) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // your task
        std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;

        // sleep a little
        ::usleep(1000000);
    }
}


int main() {
    std::string str;
    boost::thread t(thread_function);

    while(true) {
        std::cout << "Type 'quit' to exit: ";

        // will read user input
        std::getline(std::cin, str);

        if (str == "quit") {
            // the user wants to quit the program, set the flag
            boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(stopMutex);
            stop = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // wait for the async task to finish
    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `boost::atomic<bool> stop;`? The compiler doesn't know anything about a thread being created so it would be free to assume that `stop` never changes while `thread_function()` is running. It might store the initial value in a register and never update it from memory.